# What is a vendor when talking about java?

Tags: java

What is it exactly? The most information I could find this code (from http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/find-java-vendor/)

```
public class GetJavaVersionAndVendor {

    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        String version=System.getProperty("java.version");
        String vendor=System.getProperty("java.vendor");

        System.out.println("Java Version Is: "+version);
        System.out.println("Java Vendor Is: "+vendor);
    }

}
```

This code gave me the name "Oracle Corporation" which I guess is the developer of the Java version I currently have installed.

I also found out that the properties for listed as "Sun Microsystems Inc" have been rebranded to "Oracle Corporation". Thus, I make the assumption that this "vendor" has a property file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vendor is just the creator/maintainer of the JVM. Sun was bought by Oracle a couple of years ago so the "Sun JVM" more or less got relabeled as the "Oracle JVM". There are a lot of different JVM implementations. Each one has to follow the [JVM Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/). Take a look at the full [List of JVMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines)

Answer (score 10):

Vendor means implementer of JVM, is JVM/JRE by Oracle (or) IBM (or)  Some other. Each of these have their own implementation of JVM.

Example:

```
java.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc. 
java.vendor.url = http://java.sun.com/
```

Comment: This is new to me, each of own implementation of JVM? I'm curious. Can you please provide some links?

Comment: [IBM has a JDK](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/), [HP has one (for the HP/UX)](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPUXJAVAHOME), [Apache Harmony](http://harmony.apache.org/) probably has yet another vendor string, ...

Answer (score 3):

A `JVM` can be developed by different companies if it follows the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/). You could even make your own implementation if you wanted to read through the specification. The "Oracle Corporation" that you saw shows the Oracle developed your current JVM. Different companies make their own JVM's if they aren't satisfied with the Oracle one. For example, a custom JVM should still be able to run Java code correctly but it might offer some advanced security.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply fire command from command prompt to get java.vendor detail

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

or you may refer below url for more info on Java properties

https://www.applicationproductionsupport.com/2019/05/how-to-get-java-vendor-information-and.html

Answer (score 2):

From  [oracle javatutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

> "java.vendor" :   JRE vendor name

Vendor can be Oracle, IBM or others

Comment: That's somewhat self-explanatory.